# Check if SQL expression field return values in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am using this SQL expression field in my report and when the query has records it works perfectly but when it doesn't show me nothing. What I need to do is check to see if it has records and it should not display the field `LinhasDoc.Quantity` otherwise display the query `SELECT Quantity From LinhasDoc`. Can someone help me please?

Expression:

```
(SELECT LinhasDoc.Quantity- SUM(QuantTrans) FROM LinhasDocTrans WHERE IdLinhasDocOrigem = LinhasDoc.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click the `Quantity` - Format Object

Next to the Supress check box theres a button for formulas (x+2)

Click it and try this:

```
if {field} = "" then 
 true;
```